# Any Loop Holes for Owner Occupancy?

Tags: investing, real-estate, law, financing

My Client wants to buy a Fannie Mae property in WA as an owner occupant.  He owns another home out of state (in california).  He has family that lives here in WA.  This particular Fannie house in WA has a detached structure in the backyard which can easily be made into an office and storage for his truck which he needs a place to keep.  CAN HE Legitimately... and LEGALLY purchase the house as an Owner Occupant JUST intending to Occupy and Use the Detached structure in the back and RENT Out the house?  The detached structure would be His... sorta like a MIL for when he visits and he would pay a fair portion of the Utilities for retaining part of the property for his own personal use.  The house on the other hand would be rented out so I'm hoping just occupying part of the property qualifies him as an Owner Occ.  It is a SFR-Detached home

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 and 3 family houses that have an "owner occupied" clause for certain financing. Of course, one would rent out the extra apartments without question.

The key thing is that owner-occupied means just that, occupancy for tax purposes. Just using a small area like an office won't satisfy the requirement, so no, this isn't legal.